# Disable "The field must be a number" validation message for a field in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi Can anyone please tell me how can i disable  "The field must be a number" validation message for a field in MVC.

Comment: do you mean on the client or during model binding on postback?

Comment: It is during Model Binding on postback

Comment: You probably need a custom model binder - it is trying to stuff a string into a number field and the conversion and it can't. Or you validate on the client with a regex or datatype validation and prevent invalid data.